# Laplace transformation of $\frac{\cos x}{x}$

Tags: laplace-transform

How would you find the laplace transformation of $\frac{\cos x}{x}$?
Like I know you need to add it to another transformation to solve for it. And I know that the transformation of $\cos x$ is $\frac{s}{s^2+1}$ and the transformation of $\frac{f(x)}
{x}$ is $\int_s^\infty \! F(u) \, \mathrm{d}u$.

And I know that for the transformation of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ you apply it to the integral multiplying $e^{-sx}$
I am just having trouble trying to apply this with $\cos$. And actually how it works all together.
I am trying to further understand how this concept actually works. thanks.

Comment: the integral does not converge at $x\to0$

Comment: As far as I know, that formula for $f(x)/x$ is correct if $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(f/x)<\infty$.

Comment: @SofiaJune: Are you sure it is not $\frac{1- \cos x}{x}$?